# String cannot be read into R editor, possible hidden characters

Tags: r

I have created an R script that allows me to install all the packages from one machine into another (useful for when I upgrade to a new machine or need to uninstall and reinstall R).

It *used* to work. But now I am seeing some curious behaviour I don't understand.

To get the packages installed on the old machine I use the following code, which lists all the packages as a named vector of strings.

```
In_P <- installed.packages()[,1]
In_P

                  abind                 acepack                  actuar                  admisc 
                "abind"               "acepack"                "actuar"                "admisc" 
                    AER                    afex              AICcmodavg                 alabama 
                  "AER"                  "afex"            "AICcmodavg"               "alabama" 
              alphahull                    alr4                     aod                     ape 
            "alphahull"                  "alr4"                   "aod"                   "ape" 
                 api2lm                     arm            arrayhelpers                   arrow
```

Then I use the `toString()` function which concatenates all these elements into a single string with each package separated by a comma, like this.

```
toString(In_P)

[1] "abind, acepack, actuar, admisc, AER, afex, AICcmodavg, alabama, alphahull, alr4, aod, ape, api2lm, arm, arrayhelpers, arrow, arsenal, asciicast, ash, ashr, AsioHeaders, askpass, assertthat, ATR, aTSA, AUC, av, aws.s3, aws.signature, backports, base64enc, base64url, basefun, BayesFactor, BayesFM, BayesianTools, bayesm, bayesplot, bayesQR, bayesreg, bayestestR, BB, bbmle, bdsmatrix, beeswarm, bench, benchr, betareg, BH, BiasedUrn, bife, bigassertr, biglm, bigparallelr, bigutilsr, bild, bindr, bin
```

This allows me to copy-paste this large string in an email which I send to myself, copy into a new script in Rstudio on the second computer and pass it into an object, like so

```
packVec <- "abind, acepack, actuar, admisc, AER, afex, AICcmodavg, alabama, alphahull, alr4, aod, ape, api2lm, arm, arrayhelpers, arrow, arsenal, asciicast, ash, ashr, AsioHeaders, askpass, assertthat, ATR, aTSA, AUC, av, aws.s3, aws.signature, backports, base64enc, base64url, basefun, BayesFactor, BayesFM, BayesianTools, bayesm, bayesplot, bayesQR, bayesreg, bayestestR, BB, bbmle, bdsmatrix, beeswarm, bench, benchr, betareg, BH, BiasedUrn, bife, bigassertr, biglm, bigparallelr, bigutilsr, bild, bindr"
```

In order to get this string back into a vector of single package names I use `str_split` from the `stringr` package on the `packVec' object, which, in the past, gave me a vector of strings with all the package names, which I then install in one go via install.packages.

The problem I am having now is that when I try to create the `packVec` object it does not complete the action. I get that annoying `+` sign at the bottom of the console (see picture below) indicating the code isn't completing.

[image]

Also in the editor I am getting a `<hide>` sign automatically added to the end of the string (see also picture). I have no idea what this is and have never seen it before.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? Could it be that there are hidden symbols somewhere in this text string that, when copied into the new computer, cause it not to read the string as ended?

Alternatively maybe someone could suggest another way of getting the list of packages into the new computer for installation?

This used to be a simple procedure and I am at a complete loss. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell what's going on from the partial view in the screenshot. An alternative approach would be to save variable In_P on the first computer, transfer it to the second computer, and load it from there.

On the first computer: save(In_P, "/path/to/file/in_p.RData").

On the second computer: load("/path/to/file/in_p.RData"); install.packages(In_P)

Comment: BigFinger's approach would work much better than your current approach. Alternatively, have you considered using renv: https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html. You can then simply email the package.lock file to yourself

That also makes sure that you install the right versions of your libraries...

Comment: Ah yes whay didn't I think of an RData file? Idiot! Thank you. If you out in an answer I'll accept it. While we're here do either of you know what that `<hide>` thing is? Have you seen that before. I tried searching but couldn't get an answer.

Comment: How long is your  character string? R has a limit on the length of a line entered at the console. From memory, it’s 4095 bytes ( usually 4095 characters), but I could be wrong. That may  *explain* why you’ve got the problem, and why it’s only recently occurred. Other commenters have given you alternatives that are far superior to your current approach.